# Risk to perform a Penetration Testing in production environment

Tags: penetration-test, integrity, availability

Let's say I have a web server exposed on Internet that deals with confidential data and it has high requirements in terms of integrity and availability.

What are the risks to perform a penetration test in a production environment and what precautions I would take into consideration in technical and organisational terms?

Comment: It sounds like you already know the risks. The precautions are pretty straightforward: don't test your live site.

Comment: If I knew the risks, I didn't make the question. Suppose that I must test on production environment.

Comment: The risks are just as you said: breach of data confidentiality, data integrity and system availability. A pentester might find a weakness and gain access to confidential data, or to rewrite data, or bring down the system.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/241010/how-can-we-safely-allow-a-client-to-perform-penetration-testing